# How to properly create a Tree?

Tags: tikz-qtree

I'm failing at the most basic of creating a tree with `tikz-qtree`. If I copy the correct string with correct formatting into Overleaf everything works fine. But if I do change too much it just breaks. Resulting in an Emergency stop within the compiler.
This is my current attempt:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=up]
            \Tree[.$\emptyset$ [.B 
                [.A [.E]
                    [.F] ]
                        [.C ]]
                            [.D ]]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Did I mess up the formatting or something else? I'm just clueless!

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Pleas, extend your code fragment to complete small document (begining with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`). Also please show, what you try to change, that this fragment not work anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have a space before the closing bracket, e.g `[.E]` needs to become `[.E ]`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=up]
  \Tree [.$\emptyset$ [.B [.A [.E ] 
                              [.F ] ] 
                          [.C ] ]
                      [.D ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]